# What constitutes eating on the eve of Yom Kippur

Tags: halacha, yom-kippur, eating

There is a [mitzvah to eat on the eve of Yom Kippur](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/yom-kippur-halachic-guide/) throughout the entire day. Anecdotally I have heard that people chew gum in order to be 'eating' every moment of the day. I would like to know if there are any poskim who discuss if this would actually qualify as eating, especially after any sugars in the gum are consumed and the person is essentially chewing something with no nutritional value.

Comment: Why would they need to be eating every moment of the day before yom kipur? There are only two meals that need to be eaten.